# What is the best way to create derived properties

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have a datamodel with to-many to-many relations. Using the example of employee database let say the entity division is related to department which in turn is related to employee. The employee has an attribute salary. How best to have a attribute at the level of division which is derived from the salary attribute. For example average salary or maximum salary.

I would need those attributes to sort the list of departments.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this question](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-SW3) in the Core Data FAQ. If you can't do it with [KVC set/array operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE), then you try to do the `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey :` trick. If that isn't viable, you have to use KVO to observe changes in the key path the value is derived from.

Comment: Your first link is broken.  It looks like the [Core Data FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html) has moved, but I don't know which specific article you were referencing.

Comment: Link broken again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [KVC Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).  Using one of these (@avg in your example) wrapped in a custom read only property should fit the bill.